# Add overlay image on top of other image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

Suppose that I have an RGB image `RGB` and a binary image `binary` that contains the result of segmentation of image `RGB`. How to draw the image `binary` on top of image 'RGB` and show the segmentation as a red transparent area? I tried the following but I got an error. Please help me to figure out the best way in MATLAB

```
I=imread('RGB.png');
[M,N,C] = size(I);
h=imshow(I);
alpha= imread('binary.png');
alpha = cat(3,alpha,zeros(M,N), zeros(M,N));
set(h, 'AlphaData', alpha);
```

Here are the input images:

[image: RGB]

[image: binary]

Comment: Any chance you could post the input images?

Comment: @MichaelTr7 posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method to add red overlays in select regions of the mask. Modifications to these scripts can be made to fill in the remaining regions with the colours white or black. The regions of interest on the mask are selected using a logical array.

### Overlay Red Over White Region of Mask

[image: Overlay Image 1]

```
Overlay_Opacity = 0.5;

Image =imread('RGB.png');
imshow(Image);

Red_Channel = imread('binary.png');
White_Mask_Region = Overlay_Opacity*(Red_Channel ~= 0);

Overlay_Image(:,:,1) = White_Mask_Region;
Overlay_Image(:,:,2) = 0;
Overlay_Image(:,:,3) = 0;

hold on
Overlay = image(Overlay_Image);
Overlay.AlphaData = White_Mask_Region;
saveas(gcf,'Overlay_1.png');
```

### Overlay Red Over Black Region of Mask

[image: Overlay Image 2]

```
Overlay_Opacity = 0.5;

Image =imread('RGB.png');
imshow(Image);

Red_Channel = imread('binary.png');
Black_Mask_Region = Overlay_Opacity*(Red_Channel == 0);

Overlay_Image(:,:,1) = Black_Mask_Region;
Overlay_Image(:,:,2) = 0;
Overlay_Image(:,:,3) = 0;

hold on
Overlay = image(Overlay_Image);
Overlay.AlphaData = Black_Mask_Region;
saveas(gcf,'Overlay_2.png');
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply use your binary `alpha` (one layer only) as `AlphaData`.

Comment: but this does not create a transparent red overlay

Comment: That is true, but that is how alpha works. If you want to modulate RGB channels separately, you will need to compute the image accordingly, for example: I(:,:,1) = I(:,:,1) .* alpha_R + background .* (1-alpha_R) for red channel, and similar for other channels. If you need only red channel, you can do I(:,:,2:3)=0 before you apply the single layer alpha.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox, this function will do what you want:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/labeloverlay.html

Comment: That is an awesome solution!!! I had no idea that existed.